# How to set variable to name of pressed command button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will have many different buttons. I would like all the buttons to trigger the same function but I need to set a variable in the function to identify which button triggered the macro.

I'm not really sure how I should do this. Is there a way I can say like variableA = ClickedButton()?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [Application.Caller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller)

Answer (score 0):

*Hi , I think something like this should work*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
myfunction "b1"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
myfunction "b2"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
myfunction "b3"
End Sub

sub myfunction (v as variant)
msgbox v
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

*In the button module:*

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    myFunction btn_name:= Me.Name
End Sub
```

*In a normal module:*

```
Public Function myFunction(btn_name As String)
    MsgBox "The button pressed was:" & btn_name

    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Doing this, you pass the name of the pressed button (`Me.Name`) to the function as a variable, so it can be used generally inside that function.